# C++ executeable becomes sometimes faster by a factor of 3 for no obvious reason

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, cmake

My c++ project is build using cmake. Sometimes it runs approx. 3 times faster for no obvious reason.

- When I build the project from scratch in an empty build folder, all the executeables run slow in ~90% of the cases, regardless of the gcc flags.
- When I make the slow project again with a different gcc flag, e.g. -02 instead of -03, it runs fast in ~90% of the cases.
- When I touch the souces of the slow executeable, by adding comments only, and then make it again, it runs fast in 10% of the cases.

The unit tests always pass.

Has anybody seen this speedup for no obvious reason before?

- Ubuntu14.04
- cmake version 2.8.12.2
- GNU Make 3.81
- gcc 4.8.4
- Intel i7-4710MQ

default in CmakeLists.txt:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=gnu++11 -Wall -pedantic -O3 -Idir")
```

As far as I can see, the speed up effects all parts of the project. Therefore I do not think it is package related. Packages involved:

- OpenCV
- OpenMP
- GoogleTest

How do I meassure the speed:

- the unit test executeable runs 1200ms when slow and only 400ms when fast. It involves about 180 in RAM only tests and about 10 tests with disc IO. All the tests are effected in the same way, i.e. each individual test block time is about 3 times bigger in the slower case.
- the main executeable does photon propagation (scientific ray tracing), The propagation time for a bunch of photons is effected in the same way.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You might have missed a `make clean`; and you might consider simply having your (hand-written) `Makefile` (instead of generating it with `cmake` which is difficult to master)

Answer (score 1):

The `gcc` flags `-O2` and `-O3` are there to make code faster, so no surprises there.  The fact that touching files and rebuilding make it faster probably means your `cmake` isn't doing a complete rebuild.  Try doing a manual rebuild (using normal `make`) and see if things work more normally.